# How can I call the class slibing function in javascript anonymous function

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

I am trying to access the object's member function in an anonymous function by the following way-

```
  function a()
    {
      this.memb = 10;
    }

    a.prototype.hide_member = function(id){
      alert(id);
    }

    a.prototype.show_member = function(){
      setTimeout('this.hide_member(this.memb)', 2000); //Problem 1
      setTimeout(this.hide_member(this.memb), 2000); //Problem 2
      setTimeout(alert(this.memb), 2000);  //Problem 3
      this.memb++;
    }

    var obj = new a();
    obj.show_member();
```

Here, **Problem 1 -** is the code is executing exactly at right time what is given, means just after 2000 ms, but it's displaying the following error after 2000 ms -

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'hide_member'
(anonymous function)
```

**Problem 2 -** The code is executing, but it's executing immediately after the code is parsed, means not after 2000 ms.

**Problem 3 -** Same problem as in Problem 2

I am getting confusion here about these 3 problems. Thanks

Comment: FWIW: It's almost never best practice to pass a string into `setTimeout` or `setInterval`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of things are going on here:

In this code:

```
setTimeout(this.hide_member(this.memb), 2000);
```

you're **calling** `this.hide_member` immediately, and passing its return value into `setTimeout`. This is exactly like `foo(bar())`, where you're *calling* `bar` and passing its return value into `foo`.

You need to pass a function into `setTimeout`, and then call the member function from within that function. Note that within the function, `this` will be different, so you have to remember it:

```
a.prototype.show_member = function(){
  var self = this,
      memb_to_hide = this.memb;
  setTimeout(function() {
      self.hide_member(memb_to_hide);
  }, 2000);
  this.memb++;
}
```

Note that I also remembered the old value of `this.memb` to use in the function.

Another way to do that is with [ES5's `Function#bind`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.5), but it requires that the browser's JavaScript engine have that (or that you've loaded an "ES5 shim", as `bind` is a shimmable feature):

```
a.prototype.show_member = function(){
  setTimeout(this.hide_member.bind(this, this.memb), 2000);
  this.memb++;
}
```

`Function#bind` returns a function that, when called, will call the original function using the value you give in the first argument as `this` (and then passing on any further arguments). In this case, we *didn't* have to remember the old value of `this.memb` because we've already passed the old value into `bind`.

---

Side note: You're relying on the horror that is Automatic Semicolon Insertion. I recommend not doing that, and supplying semicolons at the ends of your statements, e.g.:

```
a.prototype.mumble = function() {
    /*...*/
}; // <=== Note the ;
```

Comment: Apologies for the early mistake not grabbing the original value of `this.memb` to use in the anonymous function.

Comment: Thanks, one more point I am not able to get that if the first argument in Problem 1 statement I am passing in single quote, this will be string, so how it's getting executed. I am guessing it that it automatically creating an anonymous function for it by placing the code in that function. Am I right?

Comment: @CodeCrypt, I think `setInterval` uses `eval` internally.

Comment: @CodeCrypt: `setTimeout` and `setInterval` evaluate the code in the string by firing up a parser, parsing it, and then executing it. MDN says that it's executed in global scope, not local scope, so it's not *quite* like `eval`, but it's still something to avoid whenever you can, and you almost always can. (Citing MDN because there isn't actually a specification for those yet, although [there's one brewing over at WHATWG](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/timers.html#dom-windowtimers-settimeout).)

Answer (score 1):

> is the code is executing exactly at right time what is given, means just after 2000 ms, but it's displaying the following error after 2000 ms

The error is self-explaining: `this` is referring to the global object instead of the instance of the `a` class. To avoid this you have to save a reference to the instance's context:

```
a.prototype.show_member = function(){
    var self = this; //self refers to the instance
    setTimeout('self.hide_member(self.memb)', 2000);
    this.memb++;
}
```

> The code is executing, but it's executing immediately after the code is parsed, means not after 2000 ms.

It is executed after the parsing(to be more clear it is executed when `show_member` is called in the last line) because it is a function call:

```
setTimeout(this.hide_member(this.memb), 2000);
```

`setTimeout` expects a string or a function in order to be executed properly, what you're doing here is to execute the function and return a value(nothing in this case, so it's `undefined`) which will be executed by `setTimeout` after 2000 ms. What is the result of a call to `undefined`? An error. The problem is exactly the same in the third case.

**NOTE**:
It is important to highlight that passing a string to `setTimeout` is a form of eval and it should be avoided; you can pass an anonymous function instead:

```
a.prototype.show_member = function(){
    var self = this; //self refers to the instance
    setTimeout(function() {
        self.hide_member(self.memb); 
    }, 2000);
    this.memb++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a.prototype.show_member = function(){
  var self = this;
  setTimeout('self.hide_member(self.memb)', 2000); //Problem 1
  setTimeout(function() { self.hide_member(self.memb) }, 2000); //Problem 2
  setTimeout(function() { alert(self.memb) }, 2000);  //Problem 3
  this.memb++;
}
```

Comment: Note that in all three cases, the **new** value of `memb` will be used.